# Angular app is non-uglified after I build with "prod" flag

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, npm, web-applications, aws-amplify

I am running Angular 7. My settings for `production` build contain keys `optimization=true` and `buildOptimizer=true`. I will include a chunk of full `production` config part of my `angular.json` file at the bottom.

I am running an automated build on AWS Amplify. I will also include the build config at the bottom but essentially it runs `npm run build --prod`.

The problem is that after the build is successful, I can navigate to my web app and still see all source code non-uglified (by going to Chrome developer console and viewing contents of `webpack` directory). Cannot pinpoint what did I do wrong.

`angular.json`:

```
"production": {
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  ],
  "optimization": true,
  "outputHashing": "all",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "extractCss": true,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": true,
  "budgets": [
    {
      "type": "initial",
      "maximumWarning": "2mb",
      "maximumError": "5mb"
    }
  ],
  "serviceWorker": true
}
```

Build script:

```
version: 0.1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build --prod
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist/myprojectname
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use Angular-CLI?.

Just command

> ng build --prod

I think Your 'npm run build --prod' is custom command. 
So, prod flag is undefined. dosen't it?

Comment: This seems to be the answer. Indeed, the "build" is a custom command and the "--prod" flag defined above it didn't get to it. The strange thing is it did work on my local (Windows PowerShell) but didn't work on the Linux server. As I don't have global angular CLI installed on that server, I ended up adding a new command that looked like this "build-prod": "ng build --prod". Thus I could run "npm run build-prod" and saw no webpack source maps.

Comment: I'm glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webpack then try devtool option `devtool: "hidden-source-map"` as a workaround.